# How do I send/receive data from other devices using BluetoothManager.framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have been developing an app, which sends/receives data from a non-MFi and a non-BLE device. I am using the [**BeeTee**](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) framework. I have been able pair with the device and connect to it.

Can someone please tell me how can I send/receive data to/from the device ?

I mean, what's the procedure? I am not able to think of anything further is there a socket connection involved or is there an API I need to use?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: And a link to BeeTee framework may be helpful. Why did you tagged as CoreBluetooth which is for BLE when the device is not BLE? Are you aware that you won't be able to publish the app if you the BeeTee framework you are using is this one: https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) ?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of not being able to upload to AppStore. But there can always be an enterprise store. The reason I added CoreBluetooth was it's closely related and can reach more people.

Comment: Form what I can see with that framework it allows you to turn Bluetooth on and off and perform Bluetooth scanning and discovery but it does not allow you to connect to a Bluetooth device. That would be managed using the External Accessory framework and it only works with MFi devices.

Comment: Is there no other way to achieve this with the infrastructure I have ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because you need to have a certificated Apple chip (part of MFi).

But feel free to work on [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee). :-)